# URL blacklist request

Tags: support, spam, hyperlinks

I suggest blacklisting `qmsconsultants.com`. (Warning: Chrome reports malware)

There have been three spamming attempts from different, purely spam accounts in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023754/do-minor-currency-units-have-a-iso-standard/7819635#7819635) They seem to have been triggered by the "ISO" keyword - starting to wonder if these are automated?

Comment: Is there a canonical way of reporting a URL that should be blacklisted?

Comment: As far as I know, `Moderator Attention` is the way to go (at least I've done this multiple times on SU, I don't know if those were really blacklisted or not).

Comment: @Asylum - moderators can't add strings to the blacklist, but have to make a request to the developers so posting a question on the relevant site's meta would be the best approach (cut out the middleman!)

Comment: I took the liberty to protect the question. It's unlikely to get any new, useful answers from new users anyway, so that should reduce the spam on this specific question.

Comment: @Joachim good point, could have thought of that myself. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, I realized that too while [reading Jeffs answer on another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106578/users-systematically-spamming-the-site-with-a-specific-url/106579#106579), where he talks about that they want to see a pattern before blacklisting (which would require  a post on the Meta...or at least it would be helpful).

Comment: @ChrisF: On the other hand, [back then he said a flag would be sufficient](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59748/how-to-deal-with-persistent-spam-users/59751#59751)...well, better wait for a dev to clear that up.

Comment: @Asylum - well that's a pointless step. All we'd do would be to post a meta question.

Comment: @Asylum 3 identical posts by 1-rep spam users is a reasonable pattern

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have the technology! www.qmsconsultants.com is now blacklisted. We track "hits" on blacklist entries, so we'll see soon enough whether it gets ugly.

(also, the site redirects to moksgale.com, which is *also* flagged in chrome - but one thing is certain: it is *not* a direct link to useful content)

Comment: Would this be worth adding to the blacklist for **all** sites?

Comment: What about *how* to suggest sites for blacklists? Posts on Meta or Flags?

Comment: @Asylum we don't really want an open free-for-all there; if something is attention-worthy, just flag it for mod attention (although note: only devs can manipulate the blacklist, for sanity reasons)

Comment: @MarcGravell, what about that indian web hosting company that's been doing the round on many SE sites recently? Was anything done about that?

Comment: @tombull89: yes. (Or I hope.) I raised the issue with devs after its third round on Maths, and it was then added to the blacklist (though it wasn't specified *which* blacklist).

Comment: In truth, we don't (AFAIK) get that much cross-site spam