# Should I delete SPAM content from an answer review?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, spam

In one of my first reviews in Stack Overflow, I've found this clearly SPAM answer:

> American eagle limo give you the Party Bus with Stripper Pole in DC of the extended limos for the substantially more individuals, as just constrained individuals can conform in the normal limos .The extended limo will be bigger than the customary limos with the same offices so no compelling reason to stress that whether what number of companions you do welcome for your u......Washington USA

I've flagged it as spam, but I cant delete the answer itself, so... in order to mantain forum order, *should I delete the content or i must wait to a moderator to delete it*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [possible duplicated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited):

This was recently brought up at the [Super User Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3574/should-we-replace-the-content-of-spam-posts-so-that-they-say-they-are-spam) also.

**Why shouldn't we edit spam posts?:**

- Usually spam is easy to spot, and gets removed very fast. 6 spam flags deletes the post.
- Moderators can easily see (or search for) the links posted by spammers, and can blacklist sites once it is posted enough.
- Spam doesn't usually stay there long enough for it to be cached by search engines or to have random users stumble upon it.
- As [nhinkle](https://meta.superuser.com/users/20088/nhinkle) says, most links do not even need to be removed, unless there are linking to porn, viruses, or disturbing content.
- If a post is flagged after being edited, those flags will be invalidated [if the post is rolled back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work); unless your edit actually results in a post that *shouldn't be deleted*, you're just creating an opportunity for someone to make the post stick around longer.

In short, the community is usually **too fast for spammers**, so by the time anything can happen out of it, it's already gone.

Answer (score 1):

> in order to mantain forum order, should I delete the content or i must
>   wait to a moderator to delete it?

It is better to wait for a moderator to delete it,because if we edit the content then it is difficult for the system to find Spam patterns and affect the spam detection pattern strategy.