# Prevent 0 character links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, spam, posts

[SmokeDetector](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/295232) drew our attention to [this former spam post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/62665/15950) on Biology Stack Exchange. Here's a screenshot of how it looked like:

[image]

At first, I thought it was just another 'not an answer' post, but [one of our regulars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995/j-f) noticed there was a hidden spam link inside. This was the source of the post:

```
Very informative. Thanks for sharing.
<a href="http://redacted-spam-link.example.com/"></a>
```

Concrete [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): let the content checker raise an error message when a link without a title is inserted (or, like [Jan Dvorak suggests](/questions/298403/prevent-0-character-links?noredirect=1#comment968996_298403), no letters/numbers at all). At best, the link adds nothing of value to the post, but the author might be confused where his/her link has gone; at worst, like this case, it's misused by spammers. Note that this screenshot is exactly what a ♦ moderator will see when handling a spam flag; there's nothing to indicate a hidden link. This might lead to unjustly declined flags.

Comment: Better: also disallow titles without any word characters.

Comment: And numbers, please: [1](https://example.com), [2](https://example.com). But you're right, punctuation is also quite often used to mask spam links.

Comment: Numbers are word characters. Also underscore. OK, let's disallow titles without word characters except underscore.

Comment: Ah, of course. I was confused by the definition of the word 'word'.

Comment: Haven't you heard of the word l4m3_xcu53 yet?

Comment: @Glorfindel What's wrong with numbers? Surely any title text should be allowed **as long as it is visible**.

Comment: My first comment was meant to indicate that I (sometimes) use number-only links.

Comment: @DavidPostill Let me remind you of the dot spam. Mods habitually failed to notice the period was blue and clickable.

Comment: @JanDvorak Fair point.

Comment: Meanwhile, the post was rewritten by the OP...

Comment: @Alex, yeah, the spam link was edited out by another user. That's not recommended: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/295232

Comment: I just saw this post and downvoted. (7th downvote)

Comment: @Glorfindel Even for a spammer, he is a rather lousy one. Who puts a link where you can't click? Who would click it anyway?

Comment: @Unitato they might think linking from a popular site increases their SEO score. That doesn't happen because of the `rel=nofollow` attribute (which is automatically inserted by Stack Exchange), but most spammers are stupid and don't know that.

Comment: @Glorfindel We got em' good eh?

Comment: @Unitato yes, SE is pretty effective at minimizing the effects of spam. There *is* a way to profit SEO-wise from Stack Exchange: once you have 2000 reputation, [the link in your profile does not have this attribute any longer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327588/4751173).

Comment: @Glorfindel Unrelated: is there a specific reason you deleted your answer on my question regarding flags / moderator attention?

Comment: @GhostCat yes, I need more experimenting.

Comment: @Glorfindel OK. I am so used being able to look at deleted posts - it just felt awkward to found your input gone. Beyond that - do you have any idea why my question got downvoted?

Comment: I have no idea, perhaps they just think it's 'obvious' that flagged posts are always being read.