# Dilemma after someone else edits a spam post

Tags: discussion, edits, spam

[Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/350567) - Everyone knows: **No.**

Today [someone edited a NSFW spam link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48544840/revisions) (10k on Stack Overflow) into

> [NSFW spam link]

<sup>Before clicking on the image, please note that there is an **explicit NSFW link inside**.</sup>

[image]

Seeing the edit, I thought I was under dilemma: I can't simply rollback the edit, but it doesn't comply with the meta post above. So I went on and edited that into

> [NSFW spam link, please flag as spam]

and it was no doubt another user told me not to edit spam links. I explained the issue and was forgiven.

The exact thing I'm confused about is

- If I roll the edit back, it's like I'm helping the spam link to survive (because it's already hidden), even though it's extending the life span of the link for only a minute or so. Also I would invalidate a few flags if it had already been some time after the edit, further delaying the automatic flag-nuke.
- If I "improve" the edit, well the edit has already violated the consensus, my "improvement" only makes the violation worse.

As per the accepted answer to the linked question:

> As nhinkle says, most links do not even need to be removed, **unless they are linking to porn**, viruses, or disturbing content.

This time the NSFW link is porn, so it somehow makes some sense to hide it. I would have rolled it back directly if it were a regular spam (advertisements to whatever drugs).

Next time, what should I do if I see another user edits a spam link out? Rollback or "improve"?

Comment: That is the least effective way to handle SPAM. All that was needed were 6 red flags. Instead 5 close votes and 2 delete votes are lost as well. I would have rolledback. The url is not linkyfied so anyone landing on that post either while it is life or in an audit will see it is a spam link. None of those edits were needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rollback. Flag (so spamram catches it). Presumably let team smokey know (so smokey catches it)...

There's no real dilemma here, though I disapprove of the use of edits as messaging.

Comment: But, rolling back to reveal NSFW link makes it somewhat like I want the spam to last.

Comment: Well, if there's an edit, there's no spam to filter. Just paint a big red circle around the target instead of burying it

Comment: And as well, if the rollback is performed late, it would validate a few flags.

Comment: I see you have a diamond at one of the sites, would mind such issue being handled with a custom flag? With text about like this: "This spam post was edited which made things a bit messy, could you please take care of spam, spammer and editor (meta guidance here recommends against such edits: [meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030))"

Comment: I prefer standard flags here buuuuut I seem to recall you can add in text by using the custom flag option then switching before you submit

Comment: If you roll back an edit to a post, the flag count is reset to the one at the time of that edit. So a rollback could potentially cause some flags to be ineffective and so delay the autodeletion of the post. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/270345 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876/270345

Comment: It shouldn't have been edited in the first place. And presumably people *should* have flagged it, and should keep flagging it. At worst a mod sees it, sees the spam link, and sends it off to /dev/null

Comment: That's not "at worst" - that's the best case, since a mod's spam flag => instant deletion. The worst case could be something like an edit made even before the first spam flag getting rolled back, if the editor chose to edit before flagging. :(

Comment: +1 for "rollback". We don't want to _censor_ spam, we want to _nuke_ it.