# When NAA includes rude language - red flaggable?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, not-an-answer, offensive

I know that the general rule for rude language is to edit it out if possible rather than knee-jerk red flagging it just for a few swear words or inappropriate terminology. So, for example, a post,

> Hey, does any of you [racial slur] know what the [expletive] is wrong with my [expletive] code? Here's my code [code], the [expletive] error message I'm getting is "Incorrect parsec, please load secondary module." [expletive]! [expletive]! [expletive]!!11!one

Should not be red-flagged as Rude or Abusive, but should be edited to something like:

> Hey, does anybody know what's wrong with my code? Here's my code [code], the error message I'm getting is "Incorrect parsec, please load secondary module."

Does this principle apply when a user's post is Not An Answer (NAA)? For example, the following "answer" is NAA and should be flagged as such:

> The answer above is wrong.

It's not rude or offensive, it's just NAA and needs at most an ordinary NAA flag.

Now suppose I see the following "answer":

> The [expletive] answer above is wrong. Anyone who believes it is correct is a [racial slur] and should be [violent act] in the [intimate body part]. [Expletive]!

How should that be flagged? Clearly it doesn't belong on the site, but would it be better to:

- Flag it as Rude or Abusive?
- Edit it to remove the abusive section (rendering it solely NAA) and then flag as NAA?
- Just flag it as NAA, on the grounds that it *could* have been edited to remove the offensive parts but it's just not worth doing so because the answer is doomed for deletion anyway?

Answer (score 16):

I wouldn't edit the example question you provided either, but just flag it as rude/abusive. If it's just one or two instances of 'f***ing' (of which some users, due to watching too much television, think it's OK to use as an intensifier), I'll replace that with 'very' (and then use the appropriate flag, if necessary). And I'll follow the post, if somebody does have the patience to edit it out. But so much offensive language – I'd rather spend time on somebody who does have the decency to write a normal post.

There is a gray area where some users think a post is salvageable and some don't; that's fine. We don't need to agree on everything, otherwise the world would be rather boring...

Comment: Indeed.  Some people like waffles and some people like flan.  It'd be boring if everyone liked flan, but that's because I'm pro-waffle.

Comment: @Ollie my personal favourite: Kaiserschmarrn :)

Comment: Some moderators don't want edits of flagged posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306459/282094 (see also animuson's comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362927/why-arent-rollbacks-invalidating-spam-rude-flags/362934#comment1211164_362927) as the accumulated flags quickly remove it from the front page,  and this post of yours might be a useful addition to your answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331090/282094 , if it's still correct; and your answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368168/282094 --- "**Simple** *edit fixable*" isn't flaggable, and don't edit flagged posts.