# Podcast advertising by spammers?

Tags: discussion, spam, advertising, podcast

In [podcast episode #482](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/09/09/plug-and-play-ai-for-your-own-projects-ep-482/) I was somewhat disturbed to hear an ad for turing.com

I don't particularly perceive them as a spammer, and actually don't have much of a perception of them as a company at all; but I recall recently flagging a spam post by a user named Turing and advertising turing.com. [Here is metasmoke's archived copy](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/385991)
of said spam post.

(I don't know how advertising on the podcast works; it sounded to me like the ad was part of the recording, but on other podcasts I listen to, I sometimes get ads which are clearly syndicated and distributed by the listener's geography.)

As such, this is not egregious, but a good test for whether **the podcast should have a zero-tolerance policy for advertisers who engage in abuse** of the company's services.

Sponsorship is complicated, and I don't particularly want to stipulate a policy; but I would really like to hear the rationale from Stack Overflow the company on one hand, and the Stack Exchange community's opinion on the other.

Comment: You can raise a spam flag on the podcast and when 5 users do the same the podcast will be nuked ...

Comment: @rene I wish (-:

Comment: Seriously though, this would be the one place where [editing out the spam link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited) might make sense.

Comment: So if this policy is implemented, we'll be able to kick any advertiser from SO by spamming in their name?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Joe jobs are a risk factor, of course, like they always are.

Comment: Annnnd inevitably this attracted [a spam "answer"!](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/386775) (-:

Comment: Given that most/all of the spam moderation is being done by the community, would the folks who do the podcast even be aware of which companies are spamming the site?

Comment: I would not expect them to; but I should hope they can respond when this is pointed out to them.