# Please add this URL to the spam blacklist

Tags: support, spam

Please add [image] to the URL blacklist (on Ask Ubuntu, if that's site specific).

A good part of recent spam linked to this site (always 1-rep users, lower case user names). Currently three such posts were made in the last hour:

- [Is there a reiser4 patched kernel available somwhere?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65246/is-there-a-reiser4-patched-kernel-available-somwhere/71362#71362)
- [How can I load XML data into a MySQL database?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65234/how-can-i-load-xml-through-mysql/71384#71384)
- [How do I set an external monitor as default? (Or move Unity bar to monitor at least)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65219/how-do-i-set-an-external-monitor-as-default-or-move-unity-bar-to-monitor-at-le)

Comment: Actually, going through all the other spam from today, maybe the lists [in this question/answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110025/what-can-we-do-about-the-increasing-amount-of-spam-on-ask-ubuntu) should be re-considered for blocking. :-(

Comment: You're getting both `sopgold.com` *and* `sopgame.com`?  The former wasn't in your list on the other question, so I added it.  That makes it the third duplicate URL in the cross-site spam on Drupal and Ask Ubuntu.  Also, I suggest that the other 10 URLs from this spammer which [hit Drupal](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/552) get added to the blacklist; both lists are available in [my answer to the question you linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110025/what-can-we-do-about-the-increasing-amount-of-spam-on-ask-ubuntu/110056#110056).

Comment: @KevinVermeer Yes, in the meantime a couple from those URLs in your list showed up at Ask Ubuntu too (multiple times). I guess it's safe to blacklist all the URLs in those two lists. I know that blacklisting those URLs won't put an end to the spamming, but it's at least more effective than blocking the IP addresses

Comment: http://www.midwaynissan.com/contact-form.htm  spam

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These attacks all came from a bot, I just strengthened our anti bot protection, which will be deployed today.

After this change I can track how sophisticated these bots get and will not rest until these bots either run a full blown web browser with a [full blown JavaScript interpreter](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/04/Spam+bacon+sausage+and+blog+spam+a+JavaScript+approach) or discover an algorithmic solution to reCAPTCHA.

Comment: Or become so sophisticated they start [creating automated constructive answers to survive](http://xkcd.com/810/).

Comment: obligatory +1 for obligatory xkcd reference

Comment: "...run a full blown web browser with a full blown JavaScript interpreter..." - like FlackBot only evil instead.